Как просто запустить Java программу через консоль?
Я пытаюсь найти простой способ, чтобы запустить программу через консоль (компилировать в джарник, а потом его запускать неудобно).
Через exec-maven-plugin выдает ошибку ClassNotFound:

Maven:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.copytrading.TradingBotRunner</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Ошибка:
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.copytrading.TradingBotRunner    
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.copytrading.TradingBotRunner
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:476)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)


Прикрепите полностью POM, пожалуйста, чтобы иметь более содержательную информацию, а не ошибку и плагин из конфигураций.

Проверьте, что у Вас правильно прописан main class в:<mainClass>com.copytrading.TradingBotRunner</mainClass>
Так как ругается на него.
Необходимо указать полный путь из package + имя класса в котором находится метод public static void main(String[] args)
Для такой структуры:
package com.mycompany.myproject.shoprestservice;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...
  }
}

Получится такой путь:
<mainClass>com.mycompany.myproject.shoprestservice.Main</mainClass>


could you give an example, because this doesn't work 
src.main.java.com.copytrading.TradingBotRunner


@АртёмКурилко Дополнил ответ

а, полное имя пакета и класса правильно прописано изначально

добавил картинку

@АртёмКурилко да, тогда у вас все верно прописано, и пока не понятно почему не находит класс
